# Change compact date picker text color. Always black

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uidatepicker, ios15

I have inserted a UIDatePicker in `.compact` format, only date, in Swift.

I have done several tests and read many posts but I can not change the color of the text which always remains black.

```
 pickerInizio.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "textColor")
 pickerInizio.tintColor =  UIColor.lightGray
```

How can I change the DatePicker's text color when using UIDatePickerStyleCompact?

Xcode 13, iOS 14/15

[image: Date Picker]

Comment: textColor works only for `preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels`

Comment: thanks, but in the .compact version it is not possible to change the color of the text? I don't want to change the one on the calendar but the one you see first. Oct16, 2021

Comment: I dont think apple wants you to modify these components. Their job is to differentiate iOS from other platforms and they want all apps to speak a similar design language. If you want customization you need to build your own components from scratch. But as a workaround/hack you can show a custom button with your own style and use the date picker when the user clicks on that button

Comment: Have you tried `UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDatePicker.self]).textColor = .purple`?

Comment: @Scott Thompson
 thanks your system works but once clicked and you return from the choice of the date it turns black, however it is already a step forward :-)